# Are tags hierarchical?

Tags: discussion

For some tags, a hierarchy would be good. For example, "hydraulic-disc-brake" should be a subset of "disc-brake" which should be a subset of "brake"

Otherwise, we have to use all three tags and that's a clutter. Thoughts?

Comment: There are hydraulic rim brakes (past and present) so right away your proposed hierarchy will not cover all  cases.

Comment: One of the hardest parts of using a new tag system (like asking a question on a SE stack that you don't use much) is knowing the words to use.  Synonoms don't really cover the need, because they subsume one tag into the other.  Using the five most relevant tags is probably best, but not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You could use all 3 tags, or just one of them. Most people will search by words or come from google and if the words appear, it will come up. So I don't think its really a big deal or matters.

---

One way would be to mark them as synonyms. They aren't *really* synonyms, but the tag is still shown as the one you have.

I don't think disc brake is a good example -- each brake needs its own way of dealing with it (e.g. mechanical disc vs hydraulic).

Answer (score 1):

Tags and hierarchies are fundamentally different approaches to taxonomies. I realize that there are hierarchical tag systems out there (gmail uses one, for example), but this removes opportunities for using tags effectively. If the system supports it (it does) and people can be troubled to learn the technique, it would be better to use "hydraulic" "disc" and "brake" as three separate tags, and let people search for the **intersection** of those three when needed.